# Structural Ring Oscillator VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm facing problems with the following ring oscillator code:

```
entity OSCILLATOR is
    port(   OUTPUT: out std_logic
    );
end entity OSCILLATOR;

architecture structural of OSCILLATOR is

component DEL_INV is
    generic(D: time);   
    port(   INPUT: in std_logic;
            OUTPUT: out std_logic   
        );
end component DEL_INV;

signal conn: std_logic := '0';
signal conn1: std_logic := '1';
signal conn2: std_logic := '0';
signal de: time := 2 ns;

begin
    INV1: DEL_INV generic map(de) port map (conn, conn1);
    INV2: DEL_INV generic map(de) port map (conn1, conn2);
    INV3: DEL_INV generic map(de) port map (conn2, conn);

    OUTPUT <= conn;

end architecture;
```

In particular, while simulating it, the output is always U.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: You do not show what is bound to the 3 instances of your `DEL_INV` component. My intuition is that nothing is bound and the simulator considers it as a black box which output is always `U`. Try, maybe, to instantiate an entity, instead? Or add a configuration for all instances of your `DEL_INV` component that tells the simulator which entity/architecture pair to use..

Comment: entity DEL_INV is
    generic(D: time);   
    port(   INPUT: in std_logic;
            OUTPUT: out std_logic   
        );
end entity DEL_INV;

architecture s of DEL_INV is 

begin
    OUTPUT <= INPUT after D;

end architecture s;

Comment: Yes, this is the entity/architecture you designed but my question was more "_how did you tell your simulator that instances of component `DEL_INV` are bound to entity/architecture `DEL_INV(s)`?

Comment: Just by the instantiation of them (generic map port map). But since there is just 1 single architecture for them, I assume (like every other block I simulated) Modelsim uses that only one. And all the other parts work fine.

Comment: Could you just try to add `for all: DEL_INV use entity work.DEL_INV(s);` after your component declaration?

Comment: Still not working

Comment: OK, then your simulator was probably already using a name-based default binding strategy and the problem comes from elsewhere. By the way, didn't you forget the `not` in your description of the `DEL_INV(s)` architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial values assigned to the signals `conn*`, to ensure well-defined start condition in simulation, are overwritten at start by an `'U'` driven by the `OUTPUT` on the `DEL_INV` module, and the simulation thus ends up stuck in all `U`.

One solution is to handle the initial value through the `DEL_INV` module with a generic that allows different initial `OUTPUT` values, and then use this initial value on the `OUTPUT` until the value is well defined as `'0'` or `'1'`, which can be detected through the `is_x` function.

Updated code for this is shown below.  Note that I added the suggestions by Renaud Pacalet for `for all: DEL_INV use entity work.DEL_INV(s);` and inverter (`not`) in `DEL_INV`.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DEL_INV is
  generic(
    D: time;
    XOUT: std_logic);
  port(
    INPUT: in std_logic;
    OUTPUT: out std_logic);
end entity DEL_INV;

architecture s of DEL_INV is
  signal PRE : std_logic;
begin
  PRE <= (not INPUT) after D;
  OUTPUT <= XOUT when is_x(PRE) else PRE;  -- Drive XOUT if is_x to clean up
end architecture s;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity OSCILLATOR is
  port(
    OUTPUT: out std_logic);
end entity OSCILLATOR;

architecture structural of OSCILLATOR is

component DEL_INV is
  generic(
    D: time;
    XOUT: std_logic);
  port(
    INPUT: in std_logic;
    OUTPUT: out std_logic);
end component DEL_INV;

for all: DEL_INV use entity work.DEL_INV(s);

signal conn  : std_logic;
signal conn1 : std_logic;
signal conn2 : std_logic;

constant DE : time := 2 ns;

begin

    INV1: DEL_INV generic map(de, '0') port map (conn, conn1);
    INV2: DEL_INV generic map(de, '1') port map (conn1, conn2);
    INV3: DEL_INV generic map(de, '0') port map (conn2, conn);

    OUTPUT <= conn;

end architecture;
```